# Impute NA of a Categorical Variable based on the Timing of Appearance

Tags: r, time-series, na, imputation

I have a dataset like below, with unique firm-year observations. But the variable IndustryCode has some NA due to the merger earlier.

```
stkcd date industrycode
10    2002   .
10    2003   .
10    2004   E22
10    2005   E22
10    2006   E22
10    2007   E22
10    2008   G45
10    2009   G45
10    2010   .
10    2011   .
11    2001   .
11    2002   .
11    2003   D23
11    2004   D23
....
```

I want to impute NA with the value from the closest year of the same firm. For example for firm 10(stkcd=10), IndustryCode in the years before 2004 is changed to E22, the value from 2004, and NAs in the years after 2009 is replaced by G45, the value from 2009.

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about apply two times the `na.locf` function from `zoo`?

Basically it substitutes `NA` with the last value, you'll need to go backwards too.

Some data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  stkcd = rep(10, 10),
  year = 2002:2011,
  type = c(NA,NA, "E22", "E22","E22", "E22", "G45", "G45", NA, NA)
)


library(zoo)
dat$type <- na.locf(dat$type, na.rm = F) # computes NA with the last value found
dat$type <- na.locf(dat$type, na.rm = F, fromLast = T) # this because you start with NAs, so you need to go backwards too

# output:

# stkcd year type
# 1     10 2002  E22
# 2     10 2003  E22
# 3     10 2004  E22
# 4     10 2005  E22
# 5     10 2006  E22
# 6     10 2007  E22
# 7     10 2008  G45
# 8     10 2009  G45
# 9     10 2010  G45
# 10    10 2011  G45
```

If you have multiple company, you need to `group_by` first, from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dat %>%
    group_by(stkcd) %>% # the variable used for the company name
    mutate(type = na.locf(type, na.rm = F),
           type = na.locf(type, na.rm = F, fromLast = T))
```

For example with 2 companies:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  stkcd = c(rep(10, 10), rep(20,10)),
  year = rep(2002:2011, 2),
  type = c(NA,NA, "E22", "E22","E22", "E22", "G45", "G45", NA, NA,
           NA,NA, "E22", "E22","E22", "E22", "G45", "G45", NA, NA)
)

dat %>%
  group_by(stkcd) %>% # the variable used for the company name
  mutate(type = na.locf(type, na.rm = F),
         type = na.locf(type, na.rm = F, fromLast = T)) 

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   stkcd [2]
# stkcd  year type 
# <dbl> <int> <fct>
#   1    10  2002 E22  
# 2    10  2003 E22  
# 3    10  2004 E22  
# 4    10  2005 E22  
# 5    10  2006 E22  
# 6    10  2007 E22  
# 7    10  2008 G45  
# 8    10  2009 G45  
# 9    10  2010 G45  
# 10    10  2011 G45  
# 11    20  2002 E22  
# 12    20  2003 E22  
# 13    20  2004 E22  
# 14    20  2005 E22  
# 15    20  2006 E22  
# 16    20  2007 E22  
# 17    20  2008 G45  
# 18    20  2009 G45  
# 19    20  2010 G45  
# 20    20  2011 G45
```

Comment: Can i ask why I encounter the error: Error in na.locf(dat$type, na.rm = F) : unused argument (na.rm = F) when I use your exact dataset and the script? and Error in na.locf(dat$type) : Input x is not numeric?

Comment: mm are you sure it's from the `zoo` package? use `zoo::na.locf()`

Comment: As Andre mentioned, I do have to group the company first. Or the company 11 will take the value of company 10 if there are NA in company 11. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to group_by company!

for a given company this works:

```
inds = is.na(df1$industrycode)
resInds = sapply(df1$date[inds], function(x) { which.min( abs( x - df1$date[!inds] ) ) })

df1$industrycode[inds] <- df1$industrycode[!inds][resInds]

#   stkcd date industrycode
#1     10 2002          E22
#2     10 2003          E22
#3     10 2004          E22
#4     10 2005          E22
#5     10 2006          E22
#6     10 2007          E22
#7     10 2008          G45
#8     10 2009          G45
#9     10 2010          G45
#10    10 2011          G45
```

---

Using `data.table`

```
df1<-
    fread("stkcd date industrycode
10    2002   NA
10    2003   NA
10    2004   E22
10    2005   E22
10    2006   E22
10    2007   E22
10    2008   G45
10    2009   G45
10    2010   NA
10    2011   NA
11    2002   NA
11    2003   NA
11    2004   sE22
11    2005   sE22
11    2006   NA
11    2007   sE22
11    2008   sG45
11    2009   sG45
11    2010   NA
11    2011   NA") %>% setDF

na_fill <- function(data,variable) {
    inds = is.na(data[[variable]])
    resInds = sapply(data$date[inds], function(x) { which.min( abs( x - data$date[!inds] ) ) })
    data[[variable]][inds] <- data[[variable]][!inds][resInds]
    return(data[[variable]])
}

setDT(df1)[,na_fill(.SD,"industrycode"),by="stkcd"][]

#    stkcd   V1
# 1:    10  E22
# 2:    10  E22
# 3:    10  E22
# 4:    10  E22
# 5:    10  E22
# 6:    10  E22
# 7:    10  G45
# 8:    10  G45
# 9:    10  G45
#10:    10  G45
#11:    11 sE22
#12:    11 sE22
#13:    11 sE22
#14:    11 sE22
#15:    11 sE22
#16:    11 sE22
#17:    11 sG45
#18:    11 sG45
#19:    11 sG45
#20:    11 sG45
```

Comment: sorry, I am not so familir with the function in R. Why do I have this problem;Error in x - df$EndDt[!inds] : non-numeric argument to binary operator?